# Sticky div on scroll

Tags: javascript, mootools, fixed, sticky

See this: http://jsfiddle.net/3yx5C/1/

I am trying to make a DIV(the green DIV) from the right column:
1. to be fixed when it meets the HEADER;
2. to be NOT-fixed when you scroll to the top and it meets the other DIVs above(*the grey DIVs);

What I can't achieve is the second part. Any ideas?

I have to mention that the grey DIVs on the right might be more than two, with flexible heights, and they can't be wrapped.

```
    <div id="HEADER"></div>
    <div id="WRAPPER">
        <div class="layout_right">
            <div style="height: 80px; background: gray;"></div>
            <div style="height: 80px; background: gray;"></div>
            <div id="right_ads">I am sticky!</div>
        </div>
        <div class="layout_middle">
            <div style="width: 300px; height: 200px; background: beige;"></div>
            <div style="width: 300px; height: 200px; background: pink;"></div>
            <div style="width: 300px; height: 200px; background: blue;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

<script type='text/javascript'>
window.addEvent('domready', function() {
      function sticky_AD() {
          var headerHeight2 = $('HEADER').getSize().y;
          var window_top = $(window).getScroll().y + headerHeight2 + 20;
          var div_top = $('right_ads').getPosition().y;

          if (window_top > div_top){
              $('right_ads').addClass('fixed_AD').setStyles({'top': headerHeight2 + 20});
          } else {
              $('right_ads').removeClass('fixed_AD').setStyles({'top':'auto'});
          }
      }

      $(window).addEvent('scroll', function(){
          sticky_AD();
      });
      sticky_AD();

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this:
**Demo** [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/Khe9J/)

I added a new variable `var dist = $('right_ads').getPosition().y;` to store the original position and use it later **and** changed your `else` to a new `if` : `if (window_top < dist) {`

Code:

```
function sticky_AD() {
    var headerHeight2 = $('HEADER').getSize().y;
    var window_top = $(window).getScroll().y + headerHeight2 + 20;
    var div_top = $('right_ads').getPosition().y;
    if (window_top > div_top) {
        $('right_ads').addClass('fixed_AD').setStyles({
            'top': headerHeight2 + 20
        });
    }
    if (window_top < dist) {
        $('right_ads').removeClass('fixed_AD').setStyles({
            'top': 'auto'
        });
    }
}
$(window).addEvent('scroll', function () {
    sticky_AD();
});
var dist = $('right_ads').getPosition().y;
sticky_AD();
```